# What should be my standard choice of integer type in RPGLE?

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

When I want an integer in an RPGLE program, what data type should I choose?  I'm talking about an integer that doesn't correspond to any field in the database, just a normal general purpose integer - kind of the equivalent of an `int` in Java.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a chart from the ILE RPG Programmer's reference guide:

```
byte -  3I 0  (1-byte integer)
short-  5I 0  (2-byte integer)
int  - 10I 0  (4-byte integer)
long - 20I 0  (8-byte integer)
```

I use the 10I 0 form of integer most often.  You'll find it's used in most of your API calls as well.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the binary (signed integer) (B) or integer (unsigned integer) (I) types.  You can specify the size with the digit values of 3 (1 byte), 5 (2 bytes), 10 (4 bytes) or 20 (8 bytes).  The equivalent of a Java int would be 10B.

Comment: Note that 10B and 10I are not exactly equivalent. The 10B would accommodate a 10 decimal digit value, i.e., up to 999999999, while 10I holds up to 2147483647. (Technically, you can't have a "10B". Maximum is 9B.) The only real use of the 'B' data type is when fractional digits are desired. Otherwise, they probably never should be used. Also, integer is the "I" data type and is signed; unsigned is "U".

Comment: BTW, 'B' doesn't indicate "integer any more than 'P' or 'S' might. 'B' simply indicates the memory format. For 'B', just as with 'S' or 'P', the indication of "integer" would be specifying (0) decimal positions. The 'I' and 'U' data types cannot allow anything but (0) decimal positions and are directly intended for use as "integer" values.

Comment: @user2338816 is correct, (B)inary refers to how the data is stored.  That's the closest RPG III had to an integer type.  It should not be used today.  Instead use RPG IV's true (I)nteger and (U)nsigned Integer types.  Interesting tidbit, (B)inary values are converted to (P)acked decimal values for mathematical operations; then back to (B)inary.  Whereas true integer types are used directly.  **note: confusingly, the binary type used in DDS file specifications is a true integer when 0 decimals are specified and corresponds to the RPG IV (I)nteger types**